# Data object in jquery is undefined after replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, replacewith

I'm coding a jquery plugin and I need some buttons to have a double state (like edit/save)
I get this info via JSON and insert it in the button as:

```
node
    - current //['primary'/'secondary']
    - primary // some info
    - secondary // some info
```

Once I click the button I get here to change the action. So I want to replace the whole link through a template and the info I get from button.data.
As I want to replace not only the innerHtml but the outer, I have to use '*replaceWith*'. Then I copy the '*data*' to the new button and (ideally) delete the older one.

```
changeButtonAction : function(button, selector){
      var node = button.data('node'),
           info;

      if(node.current == 'primary'){
           info = node.secondary;
           node.current = 'secondary';
      }else{
           info = node.primary;
           node.current = 'primary';
      }

      button.replaceWith(multiReplace(OPERATION_ITEM, info, true));
      button.data('node', $.extend( true, {}, node));

      ... //bit of interaction
 }
```

**The thing is:** Once out the function **I loose the new data** as it says it's **undefined**.
Could somebody help? Using 'replaceWith' it's not a must, so if you come up with another solution it will be ok.

Comment: if possible please make a demonstration in http://jsfiddle.net/ so that others will get a better idea of your problem. No need to copy all the code , but just the part where the issue is. Use 'Add Resources ' on left side to add other js files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.

Thanks to Diode I tried reproducing it in jsfiddle. The click function did not work neither so I changes my code a bit. Instead of replacing with text:

```
button.replaceWith(multiReplace(OPERATION_ITEM, info, true));
button.data('node', $.extend( true, {}, node));
```

Do it with an object:

```
var button2 = $(multiReplace(OPERATION_ITEM, info, true))
    .data('node', $.extend( true, {}, node));
button.replaceWith(button2);
```

You can see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/p8vMR/9/